# System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException: Mailbox unavailable in sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-workflow

I have created a document library in sharepoint 2007 and i have enabled incoming email settings to the doc library. When I am trying to send an email from workflow I am getting the error...

System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay for  EmailDocLibrary@xxx.com 
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) 
   at DP.Sharepoint.Workflow.Common.SendMailWi

Do i need to setup anything before sending an email. Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outgoing mail server isn't setup for relaying from just any address. Checkwith your email server adminto make sure that you are able to send outgoing messages with the email address you have.

Comment: You can verify that your mail server admins have allowed relaying using smtp testing tools from your sharepoint server such as Telnet - http://sharepointalert.info/2009/11/troubleshooting-sharepoint-email-alerts-check-email-setupinfrastructure/

Comment: Error again! All these days it was working fine and today morning also I have tested, and it was fine. All of a sudden now i got the same error message again. NO setting have been changed mean while. Everything was as it is. Can anyone please help me again.